Wires and probability
If two people had $N$ tangled wires and each took one end of any of them, what is the probability that they would be holding two ends of the same wire? The answer is:
$$
\frac{1}{N-1}
$$
I am not really sure how to arrive at this.

Already answered, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988896/probability-of-two-people-holding-the-same-rope

Assuming that the answer OP quotes is correct, the question is different from those shown as duplicate, isn't it ?

@trueblueanil not our job to fill in any context OP omitted, even if the proffered solution seems incorrect for the problem. The question as stated is identical to those linked duplicate questions.

If there are $N$ wires there must be $2N$ ends.
total ways in which two people can hold ends of wires $=^{2N}C_2=\frac{2N!}{(2N-2)!2!}=N(2N-1)$
for them to hold ends of same wires, there are only $N$ favourable cases to choose the wire out of $N$ wires whose ends they will hold
So, favourable cases$=N$
Probability=$\frac{Favourable\ Cases}{Total\ Cases}=\frac 1{2N-1}$
There might be some error in the given answer

Not the right answer. If you have $2N$ favourable cases because the people pick at the ends sequentially, then you must also double the total number of cases as order does matter, ie $$P^{2N}_{2}=\frac{(2N)!}{(2N-2)!}=2N(2N-1)$$The answer should actually be $\frac{1}{2N-1}$, so OP's solution is still wrong.

@cambridgecircus yes you are right i will edit the solution there will be only $N$ favourable cases, but the given answer is still wrong
